# Run a function in time interval in jQuery

Tags: jquery, intervals

I want to make a banner by using jQuery. When the page loaded script will show a group of photos one by one. For example, the controller sends 10 photos and each photo will be shown in 30 seconds after 10 minutes the script demand another photo from the controller.

The question is: How can I make a function that runs in 30 sec. I need to run a function in a time interval without any button click or anything else.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The main method is:

```
 setInterval(function () {
        console.log('it works' + new Date());
    },30000);
```

If you need to clear interval in future:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
            console.log('it works' + new Date());
        },30000);
```

in the future:

```
clearInterval(myInterval);
```

Comment: I get `ReferenceError: myInterval is not defined`

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales: I got the same error. By mistake I tried to invoke the function myInterval with parenthesis.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="ticker">
    <li>Image 1</li>
    <li>Image 2</li>
    <li>Image 3</li>
    <li>Image 4</li>
    <li>Image 5</li>
</ul>​
```

**CSS:**

```
ul{height:20px; overflow:auto}​
```

**JS:**

```
var $ticker = $('ul#ticker');
var speed = 300;
var pause = 3000;

var tick = function () {
    var first = $ticker.find('li').first().animate({
        height: 0
    }, speed).hide('normal', function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $ticker.append('<li>' + first + '</li>');
    }).html();
};

$('ul#ticker').click(tick);
setInterval(tick, pause);
```

Here, a simple **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/accka/)**.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript provides a [`setTimeout` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout):

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(code, delay);
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use `setInterval` like this

```
setInterval( "alert('Hello')", 5000 );
```

Comment: It is strongly preferable to use a function or closure as first argument, not a string.