# How to process the big loop without freezing the browser using setTimeOut function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I have created two buttons .One is named 'sync' and other is named 'async'.When i click 'sync' button ,it should process the big array using loops and  it freezes the browser until the loop is completed processing the larger array.When i press the 'async' button.it should process the same large array without freezing the browser.How to do this using setTimeOut function?

Comment: Try using Web Worker.

Comment: Perhaps not exactly what you're looking for (as you specifically mention `setTimeout`), but you might find this article on web workers helpful:  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

Comment: In my view you can use `SetTimeInterval` , refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081443/run-a-function-in-time-interval-in-jquery

Comment: @RohanVeer Still web worker freezes the browser.I created a separate javascript file in which array of 100000 index was processed and printed on console.Though it runs in separate thread,wht it freezes the browser?:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a loop variable, like the following code. In this example, the function increases every element by 1. The timeout period is 1 millisecond.

```
    var currentIndex;
    function processNthElement(array) {
        if (currentIndex >= array.length)
        {
            //the whole array has been processed, do what you need to do
            //with the results here
            return;
        }

        //do what you want with the array element here
        array[currentIndex]++;

        currentIndex++;

        setTimeout(function () {
            processNthElement(array);
        }, 1);
    }
    function processArrayWithSetTimeout(array) {
        currentIndex = 0;
        processNthElement(array);
    }
```

Then to process a large array, just call processArrayWithSetTimeout(array). However since we are using timeout, you need to process the result at the very last function call(see the comment in the function). If an array has 10000 elements, it will take more than 10000 milliseconds or 10 seconds to process, but the UI won't be freezed.

Note that this still processes the array sequentially but without freezing the UI as it waits for a while after processing 1 element.

Answer (score 5):

Using async/await this in ES7 this gets pretty trivial. Example of long loop that takes too long

```js
function main() {
  const numOperations = 1000000000;
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < numOperations; ++i) {
    sum += doSomeOperation(i);
  }
  console.log(sum);
}
main();

function doSomeOperation(v) {
  return v * 1.1 / (v + 1);
}
```

Example of using async/await to make it yield to the browser once in a while

```js
async function main() {
  const numOperations =  1000000000;
  const iterationsPerChunk = 10000000;
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < numOperations; ++i) {
    if (i && i % iterationsPerChunk === 0) {
       await oneMoment();
    }
    sum += doSomeOperation(i);
  }
  console.log(sum);
}
main();

function doSomeOperation(v) {
 return v * 1.1 / (v + 1);
}

function oneMoment() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve));
}
```

Picking a good value for `iterationsPerChunk` might be harder. You could easily make some class that checks `performance.now` and only calls await when a certain amount of time has passed, say 1/2 a second or 1 second. Each call to `setTimeout` will yield for anywhere from 5ms to 20ms so you don't want to await too often but it does make it easy to use.

example using `performance.now`

```js
async function main() {
  const numOperations =  1000000000;
  let sum = 0;
  let then = performance.now();
  for (let i = 0; i < numOperations; ++i) {
  
    // calling performance.now is slow
    // so only check every 1000 iterations
    if (i && i % 1000 === 0) {
      const now = performance.now();
      
      // have 0.1 second elapsed?
      if (now - then > 100) {
        await oneMoment();
        then = performance.now();
      }
    }
    sum += doSomeOperation(i);
  }
  console.log(sum);
}
main();

function doSomeOperation(v) {
 return v * 1.1 / (v + 1);
}

function oneMoment() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve));
}
```

Update:

I heard a rumor the time restraints on `setTimeout` might be removed because you can work around them by posting a message to yourself via `postMessage`.

You still have the same issue that postMessage does take some amount of time but it's generally microseconds or less.

```js
const pause = (function() {
  let reqId = 0;
  const reqs = new Map();

  window.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
    const resolve = reqs.get(e.data);
    if (resolve) {
      reqs.delete(e.data);
      resolve();
    }
  });

  return _ => new Promise(resolve => {
    const id = reqId++;
    reqs.set(id, resolve);
    window.postMessage(id);
  });
})();

async function main() {
  const numOperations =  1000000000;
  const iterationsPerChunk = 10000;
  const startTime = performance.now();
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < numOperations; ++i) {
    if (i && i % iterationsPerChunk === 0) {
       await pause();
    }
    sum += doSomeOperation(i);
  }
  const elapsedTime = performance.now() - startTime;
  console.log(sum);
  console.log(`elapsedTime: ${(elapsedTime * 0.001).toFixed(2)}seconds`);
}
main();

function doSomeOperation(v) {
 return v * 1.1 / (v + 1);
}

function oneMoment() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve));
}
```

Comment: Super cool! Thank you. `` await oneMoment(); `` is what I was looking for!

Comment: What does `new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve))` do? Does it free up the event queue momentarily?

Comment: all it does is create a promise that resolves when `setTimeout` calls `resolve`. The part that makes it free up event queue is declaring main as `async` and using `await`. See [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

Comment: Sorry for a newbie question, I'm trying to understand how the second approach is faster without messing up the logic. I don't understand how any code after `await` is assured to get executed.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. That's the way `await` works. Read the mdn article I linked to or go [read some tutorials on async/await](https://www.google.com/search?q=async+await+javascript). I also don't know what you mean by faster. The second approach is not faster, the point is it doesn't freeze the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is  asingle thread engine. so large computation will temporary block all other event. You can use [**Web worker**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) to run such big scripts in the background

Comment: Ya web woker makes the job easier.And it's a way of introducing multi-threading to js.Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion, declare `setTimeout` as a variable to be able to "break" recursive call to function which calls `setTimeout()`

```
var curr, fn = (arr, i = -1, n = arr[++i]) => 
                 curr = setTimeout(() => {
                          // do stuf with `n`: current index in `arr` array
                          console.log(n);
                          // recursively call `fn` if condition met; e.g., 
                          // `i` less than `arr.length` 
                          i < arr.length ? fn(arr, i) : (curr = void 0)
                        }, 0);

// e.g.
fn(Array(10000).fill(1));
// clear timeout, stop recursion 
clearTimeout(curr);
```

Comment: What does Array(10000).fill(1) mean?

Comment: Got it .Got it.But showing error in   "var curr, fn = (arr, i = -1, n = arr[++i]) => "  saying that "Expected ) "