# How to prevent the page from freezing in long loops, without loosing the precision from the "for" or the "forEach"?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Using a for with big numbers make the browser freeze or even crash. Is there a way to run these loops and not freezing the page?

Using Promisses, async functions maybe? How should i do that?

Exemple:

```js
for(i=0; i<1000000000; i++){}
```

Im developing a MIDI player in a website, i need the precision that comes from the `for` or the `forEach` instead of adding one millesecond using `setInterval`.

```js
var renderTrack = (track, play) => {
      track.notes.forEach(note=>{
        if(play){
          notesArr.push(setTimeout(()=>{
            pianoPress(note.name + note.octave, note.velocity);
          }))
        }
      })
    }

    MIDI.tracks.forEach(track=>{
      renderTrack(track, true);
    });
```

Comment: And/or use `timeout` or `interval` to break task into chunks?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to process the big loop without freezing the browser using setTimeOut function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38735201/how-to-process-the-big-loop-without-freezing-the-browser-using-settimeout-functi)

Comment: Another interesting post (on node but it applies also in browser): https://snyk.io/blog/nodejs-how-even-quick-async-functions-can-block-the-event-loop-starve-io/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: Im makeing an midi player, so i need precision in the songs, this 1 milissecond in each note can cause wierd timing in long pieces. I was searching for something that doesnt take out this precision from the for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I craeted my own `promise`.

`setTimeout` can gave a small timing delay so it was not the best option to this issue as this small timing can mess the timing of the whole song.