# How to run Ajax after every 5 second

Tags: php, ajax

I want to call my ajax after every 5 seconds. Below code is showing the html once but not calling the ajax after every five seconds. I am new in ajax, Can somebody explain this to me please.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function fresh_ajax(){
        $.ajax({ 
           type:"POST",
            url:"pic.php",
            success:function(html){
                $('.a').empty();
                $('.a').html(html).show();
            }   
        });
    }

    window.setInterval(function(){
        fresh_ajax();
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: 5 second = 5000 miliseconds, change 500 with 5000

Comment: Change 500 to 5000. 1000 milliseconds is 1 second

Comment: Possible duplicate of [run a function in time interval in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081443/run-a-function-in-time-interval-in-jquery)

Comment: guys thank you, Its working fine :)