# Run a function in time interval at controller without routing?

Tags: laravel, server

I recently developing a web service in laravel. I wanna that a function actually in time interval running in the background from a server and its output saving somewhere in a table, something like:  [Run a function in time interval in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081443/run-a-function-in-time-interval-in-jquery).

Comment: It's really my matter buddy, Please everybody can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something for the task/command scheduler.

> "Laravel's command scheduler allows you to fluently and expressively define your command schedule within Laravel itself. When using the scheduler, only a single Cron entry is needed on your server. Your task schedule is defined in the app/Console/Kernel.php file's schedule method." - [Laravel Docs 5.6 - Task Scheduling  - Intro](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling#introduction)

`App\Console\Kernel`:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        // something to run every minute here
    })->everyMinute();

    // artisan command
    $schedule->command('some:command')->daily();

    // queued job
    $schedule->job(new SomeJob)->everyThirtyMinutes();

    ...
}
```

[Laravel Docs 5.6 - Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling)